# Watch for files to change and call git commit when they are new

Tags: git, bash, github

I do not know bash very well and I have no idea how I would do this, essentially I want to say when a user does `bin/build` it will move a set of directories over. so lets assume you have a project like such:

```
ProjectName/
  bin/build
  FolderOne/
  FolderTwo/
```

In this project you do `bin/build` it will copy folder one to a directory, and folder two to another directory. It will then CD in to folder one, check if the files have changed. If so call `git add -A && git commit -a` to make sure all the files are added (or removed) then let the user enter in the commit message, upon exiting or saving the commit message it will then push. After that it will then move on to the next folder, in this case folder two and so on and so on ...

I can make it cp the contents of a directory and move that over to the directory I specify. I can even cd into those directories in bash. What I have no idea how to do is say: *Hey have the contents of this directory changed? yes? do this, now thats done lets move on. Oh they haven't changed? lets move on to the next directory.*

This is what I currently have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eux

# We need directories set up.
mkdir -p ~/vagrant/Freya-Factory
mkdir -p ~/vagrant/Freya-Http
mkdir -p ~/vagrant/Freya-Loader
mkdir -p ~/vagrant/Freya-Loader-Assets
mkdir -p ~/vagrant/Freya-Templates

# Now we need to move the contents over.
cp -a Factory/. ~/vagrant/Freya-Factory/
cp -a Http/. ~/vagrant/Freya-Http/
cp -a Loader/. ~/vagrant/Freya-Loader/
cp -a Loader/Assets/. ~/vagrant/Freya-Loader-Assets/
cp -a Templates/. ~/vagrant/Freya-Templates/

# Now we need to walk through each ~/vagrant/ sub directory and see if the files in each
# has changed. If they have, we need to do git add -A && git commit -a followed by a git push.
#
# If the files in the directory have not changed, then we need to move on to the next directory.
```

- Should I hook into `git status`? and say if git status comes back with files, then do my commands?

**Whats the easiest way to accomplish this?**

Comment: `git status` sounds like a good idea. I found this: `--porcelain
Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts`

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do this? You should care more about your version history than the fact that some random developer on your team just happened to issue a build now and then. *Why* did he do a build? *What* did he change? *Why* did he change it? The reason you're finding no easy tools to automate this is that this problem is not common at all. Why not let the developer purposely commit his changes when he's done with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git add -A` will do nothing if there is nothing to add/remove.

If `git add -A` does nothing then `git commit -a` (do you really need `-a` here?) will have nothing to do and will do nothing.

If `git commit -a` did nothing then `git push` will not have anything to push and will do nothing.

In which case you are done and you can just move on.

If `git add -A` *does* do something then `git commit -a` will have something to do and will launch the editor (in interactive mode at least) and will then commit the changes. If `git commit -a` committed a change then `git push` will have something to push and will do that.

So, barring errors in that workflow (which will almost certainly happen and you should try to account for) I believe you can just use

```
git add -A
git commit (-a)
git push
```

and be done with it, no?

Comment: I could get away with that but it should check before doing that, why run three commands when you could run one before wasting "resources" running three.

Comment: @TheWebs I would fully expect that you are going to waste virtually identical (and potentially greater) resources attempting to test for status before running the commands as `git status` and similar commands are going to need to do much the same work that `git add -A` is going to do to add the changed files anyway. But feel free to check the work time of the three commands versus the status + three commands versus just status in various cases and see.